# TwitterKit sharing fail on iPhone5S (iOS8.4), but fine work simulator iPhone 5S (8.4)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, twitter-fabric

I tried to share some string and image on my application. Sharing success on iPhone 6(9.3), and simulator iPhone 5S(8.4, 9.3).

But I failed sharing on iPhone 5S(iOS 8.4)

[Twitter account on Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biv83.jpg)

There are my code and crashes.

- Code:

  ```
  let composer = TWTRComposer()  
  let postMessage = "Twitter sharing test"  
  let viewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController!    


  composer.setText(postMessage)  
  composer.setImage(UIImage(named: "Twitter_Icon"))  

  composer.showFromViewController(viewController!) { result in  
      if (result == TWTRComposerResult.Cancelled) {  

      }    
      else {    
      }  
  }
  ```
- Crash:

  ```
  2016-07-11 06:49:40.923 airdropTest[1600:294752] [Fabric] Unable to locate application icon   
  2016-07-11 06:49:40.971 airdropTest[1600:294752] [Crashlytics] Version 3.7.2 (112)    
  2016-07-11 06:50:05.645 airdropTest[1600:294752] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target .' * First throw call stack: (0x18554c22c 0x1971c80e4 0x18a2ea898 0x18a2ec734 0x18a0b5f40 0x1001c8af4 0x1001014a8 0x100101574 0x18a6ae7f4 0x18a2ceab0 0x18a2d0f2c 0x18a0eadb8 0x18a00055c 0x18a0000c4 0x189ffffcc 0x18990962c 0x100b2cf94 0x100b31c28 0x185503544 0x1855015ec 0x18542cf74 0x18ee8f6fc 0x18a02ed94 0x100107a08 0x197872a08)     
  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)
  ```

Comment: I have the same issue when twitter is not installed on the phone.